# Find sum in array equal to zero

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of integers, find a set of at least one integer which sums to 0.

For example, given `[-1, 8, 6, 7, 2, 1, -2, -5]`, the algorithm may output `[-1, 6, 2, -2, -5]` because this is a subset of the input array, which sums to 0.

The solution must run in polynomial time.

Comment: Also why is there no "set bounty" button on my question? Does it have to be a certain age?

Comment: The subset sum problem is [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#General_discussion). There is only a polynomial-time [approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Polynomial_time_approximate_algorithm).

Comment: See the faq about your bounty question. "Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty."

Comment: @froeschli, Ah, I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: Bounty: [What if I don’t get a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty)

Answer (score 8):

You'll have a hard time doing this in polynomial time, as the problem is known as the [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), and is known to be [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).

If you do find a polynomial solution, though, you'll have solved the "[P = NP?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem)" problem, which will make you quite rich.

The closest you get to a known polynomial solution is an approximation, such as [the one listed on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Polynomial_time_approximate_algorithm), which will try to get you an answer with a sum close to, but not necessarily equal to, 0.

Comment: Well, that's why he wants to assign a bounty.  Proving P=NP comes at a price, and the OP knows that.

Comment: It's co-NP but there is a pseudo polynomial time algorithm for it, and by current limitations on normal PCs this can be done fast enough.

Answer (score 4):

This is a [Subset sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem, It's NP-Compelete but there is pseudo polynomial time algorithm for it. see wiki.

The problem can be solved in polynomial if the sum of items in set is polynomially related to number of items, from wiki:

> The problem can be solved as follows
>   using dynamic programming. Suppose the
>   sequence is
>
> ```
> x1, ..., xn
> ```
>
> and we wish to determine if there is a
>   nonempty subset which sums to 0. Let N
>   be the sum of the negative values and
>   P the sum of the positive values.
>   Define the boolean-valued function
>   Q(i,s) to be the value (true or false)
>   of
>
> ```
> "there is a nonempty subset of x1, ..., xi which sums to s".
> ```
>
> Thus, the solution to the problem is
>   the value of Q(n,0).
>
> Clearly, Q(i,s) = false if s < N or s
>
> > P so these values do not need to be stored or computed. Create an array to
> >     hold the values Q(i,s) for 1 ≤ i ≤ n
> >     and N ≤ s ≤ P.
>
> The array can now be filled in using a
>   simple recursion. Initially, for N ≤ s
>   ≤ P, set
>
> ```
> Q(1,s) := (x1 = s).
> ```
>
> Then, for i = 2, …, n, set
>
> ```
> Q(i,s) := Q(i − 1,s) or (xi = s) or Q(i − 1,s − xi)   for N ≤ s ≤ P.
> ```
>
> For each assignment, the values of Q
>   on the right side are already known,
>   either because they were stored in the
>   table for the previous value of i or
>   because Q(i − 1,s − xi) = false if s −
>   xi < N or s − xi > P. Therefore, the
>   total number of arithmetic operations
>   is O(n(P − N)). For example, if all
>   the values are O(nk) for some k, then
>   the time required is O(nk+2).
>
> This algorithm is easily modified to
>   return the subset with sum 0 if there
>   is one.
>
> This solution does not count as
>   polynomial time in complexity theory
>   because P − N is not polynomial in the
>   size of the problem, which is the
>   number of bits used to represent it.
>   This algorithm is polynomial in the
>   values of N and P, which are
>   exponential in their numbers of bits.
>
> A more general problem asks for a
>   subset summing to a specified value
>   (not necessarily 0). It can be solved
>   by a simple modification of the
>   algorithm above. For the case that
>   each xi is positive and bounded by the
>   same constant, Pisinger found a linear
>   time algorithm.[2]

Comment: co-NP and NP-complete are two different things.

Comment: It is not known to be in co-NP because if there is no solution to a given problem, there is not any known short certificate which can prove this.  It is known to be NP-complete, and hence in NP, but that does not imply membership in co-NP.

Comment: @Keith: NP=co-NP is an open problem and if an NP-Complete problem is in co-NP, then NP=co-NP.

Comment: @Moron: Yes, I know.  I'm not sure that's relevant to what Saeed was saying or my comment on it, however.

Comment: @Keith: It is relevant to your comment. A more convincing reason that it is not in co-NP is that it is NP-Complete, not that we can't find a short certificate, which is kind of true for Composite/Prime (checking if a number is composite/prime), which is in both in NP and co-NP (in fact in P). I was only agreeing and trying to make your comment more convincing. Anyway, end of discussion for me...

Comment: @Moron: But we don't know it to not be in co-NP, we just don't know it to be in co-NP.  It's true that it would be a major research result if we did identify a co-NP problem which was NP-Complete, but that doesn't imply that any individual NP-Complete problem isn't in co-NP.  But my goal wasn't to argue whether or not the problem is in co-NP, it was to give a reasonable definition of co-NP so as to distinguish it from NP-Complete.  He clearly was confused about what co-NP meant, so I provided one of several equivalent definitions of co-NP.

Comment: @Keith: I never claimed we know for _sure_ it is not in co-NP. The fact that NP=co-NP is open implies that the situation is unknown. Anyway, this discussion seems pointless. Please pardon me if I don't respond.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) which NP-complete problem.

If you are interested in algorithms then most probably you are math enthusiast that I advise you look at

- [Subset Sum problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SubsetSumProblem.html) in mathworld

and here you can find the algorithm for it

- [Polynomial time approximation algorithm](http://www.wordiq.com/definition/Subset_sum_problem)

> initialize a list S to contain one element 0.
>
> for each i from 1 to N do
>
> let T be a list consisting of xi+y,
>   for all y in S
>
> let U be the union of T and S
>       sort U
>
> make S empty
>
> let y be the smallest element of U
>
> add y to S
>
> for each element z of U in
>   increasing order do //trim the list by
>   eliminating numbers 
>         close one to another
>        if y<(1-c/N)z, set y=z and add z to S
>
> if S contains a number between (1-c)s and s, output yes, otherwise no