# Mysql (PHP): delete all rows which SUM = 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table

```
+----+--------+
| id | amount |
+----+--------+
|  1 |     10 |
|  2 |      5 |
|  3 |     -5 |
|  4 |      6 |
|  5 |    -16 |
|  6 |      4 |
|  7 |      1 |
|  8 |     -3 |
+----+--------+
```

I need to delete all rows (in order, from min ID to max ID) witch SUM = 0.

In my example, if we divide the table, I need to delete the id 1,2,3,4,5 because their SUM = 0 (10+5-5+6-16), but leave the record 6,7,8

I don't know how write the query, to read step to step the rows.

Thank you

Comment: This is nothing more than a variant of the subset-sum problem. Have a look here => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem. And see the accepted answer here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849011/find-sum-in-array-equal-to-zero

Comment: I saw your link, but I need exactly in order of insert in database (from min ID to max ID) and not "casual"...

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE a  
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , SUM(y.amount) running 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.id <= x.id 
        GROUP 
           BY x.id
     ) b 
    ON b.id >= a.id 
 WHERE b.running = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP-ish Pseudo code:

```
$data = get_data();
list($minID, $maxID, $currSum) = array($data[0]['id'], 0, 0);
foreach ( $data as $value ) {
  $currSum += $value['amount'];
  if ( !$currSum ) {
    $maxID = $value['id'];
    break;
  }
}
$sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id >= $minID AND id <= $maxID";
```